# Transferring MP3 format to FTP using python

Tags: python, ftp, mp3, transfer, distortion

I got an issue with transferring MP3 format or wav format from local to FTP. The music got distorted or even blank sounds.

I used `session.storbinary('STOR '+ fileName, fileOpen)` which causes the sound distortion. Is there any other way to transfer the files over? Or I have to do it manually?

I'm using python with ftplib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to open your local files like this:

```
f = open('something.mp3', 'rb')
```

Using `open('asd.mp3')` will treat the file as text and result in corruption. Now, I can't be sure this is the problem, but without more context this is my closest bet.

Comment: Thanks George, my mistake was i put as `f = open('something.mp3', 'r'). 
As earlier on, I used `'rb'` but my computer wrote something like a box as my file name, thus i removed the binary part from all and forget that music files are binary.

Thanks so much for your help :D